# Restrict copy/paste to be Values only for not changing conditional formatting

Tags: excel, vba

For cells that have conditional formatting, for example, Fill black color if cell contains blank, if the cells are copied and pasted to other place, the conditional formatting will change too.

Example Picture:

[image]

I understand that using "Paste Values" can keep the conditional formatting, but can we restrict the copy/paste mode to be "Values" only, so that user can only use CTRL+C/CTRL+V?

Comment: Why would you want two tables where the only difference is the color anyway? You could also simply put in F8: `=B8`

Comment: Hello! Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will start with a question. Would you buy a book without page numbers? Would you drive a car with steering wheel operating in the opposite direction? Would you cross a street where green lights are replaced with purple and red ones are replaced with blue? Would you use Excel where <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> does something funny instead of just paste? Replacing standard functionality that has been there for decades is highly **NOT RECOMMENDED.** User may view this as unexpected behavior.

But still, if you need it, this is possible, via VBA macro like this (bind this to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> in Macros menu):

```
Public Sub PasteValues()
    If Application.CutCopyMode Then
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Paste
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: THANK YOU a lot! This macro simply works. Actually, I tried to restrict the CopyPaste mode for other users that are not accustomed to selecting the modes.

Comment: "Replacing standard functionality that has been there for decades is highly NOT RECOMMENDED. User may view this as unexpected behavior." This only applies to computer-literate people, which many Excel users are not. They might not even know that Crtl+C/V exists. You can't hope to educate these people to use "Paste Values only", so altering standard functionality is the best choice.